# Find out default language on Linux

Tags: linux, posix

Is there a way to find out the default language of a Linux system from C? Is there a POSIX API for this? E.g. I'd like to have a string in human readable format, i.e. "German" or "Deutsch" on a German system, "French" or "Francais" on a French system etc. Is there something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To determine a current language on a system you can look at the following environment variables (sorted by priority in descending order):

1. `LANGUAGE`
2. `LC_ALL`
3. `LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_NUMERIC`, `LC_TIME`, `LC_COLLATE`, and others
4. `LANG`

Each of these variables has a special format: *`ll_CC`*, where the first two letters mean language code, the second two ones mean country code. Also an additional information like charset or  variant may be specified. As exception, the first variable can contain list of language codes, and it works only if localization mechanism is enabled.

At least, **gettext**, the most popular translation framework in Unix-like OS, is guided by these rules.
https://gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/gettext_2.html#Locale-Environment-Variables

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the `LANG` environment variable contains that information in the format like "de_DE.UTF-8".

You can retrieve it using the `getenv` function.

EDIT:

For more sophisticated internationalization, you might want to look into [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at getenv and setenv in relation to the environment variables LANGUAGE etc.

This has to do with locales.

http://billposer.org/Software/NumbersAndLocales.html

Be sure to note the different meanings of all the variables. There are overrides through LC_ALL etc.