# Howto get the language name for a given locale in linux

Tags: linux, locale

This is pretty much [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338279/find-out-default-language-on-linux) with a bit more information. My goal is to work out the languages installed in the system.

The following command

```
locale -a
```

displays all the languages (in a format such as en_AU.utf8). This seems to correspond to the contents of /usr/lib/locale.

Furthermore, invoking

```
LANG=fr_FR.utf8 locale -ck LC_IDENTIFICATION
```

Gives information of that particular locale which includes the language name (Which in this case is French).

This seems to be the information contained in /usr/lib/locale/fr_FR.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION.

Is there a way (maybe an API call) to obtain this info? I looked at the source of the locale utility but it uses a private struct.

Comment: You don't need to manually get the environment variable `LANG` - `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` will set the locale based on the environment settings.

Comment: You should upvote and accept Yasir's solution, not copy it to the question.  The question should remain a question only.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. Adjusted question and added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Yasir. This is exactly what I wanted:

```
#include <langinfo.h>

char *s;
s = getenv("LANG");
if (s == NULL) 
    printf("LANG is not set");
else {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, s);
    printf(nl_langinfo(_NL_IDENTIFICATION_LANGUAGE));
}
```

Comment: If anybody is looking for the language code it can be retrieved using _NL_ADDRESS_LANG_AB. And the country code can be retrieved using _NL_ADDRESS_COUNTRY_AB2.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you could just get environment variables, using, for example, [`getenv(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv), thus you would want to pass it the name of variable, e. g.:

```
char *s;
s = getenv("LANG");
if (s == NULL) 
    printf("LANG is not set");
else
    printf(s);
```

Comment: That's fine, but I want to know what the contents of LANG represent. For example, if LANG=fr_FR.utf, How do I work out that the represented language is "French"?

Comment: I think you could just test if locale have the value `fr_FR` in its name; after all, you know it is shortcut for French. The other function, which could be useful is [`nl_langinfo(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nl_langinfo).

Comment: Hmm nl_langinfo looks promising. I'll have a look at that.