# Get the name of a language given its code, and vice versa

Tags: bash, iso-639

How can I get the English name of a language given its two-letter code (see [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) and [List of ISO 639-1 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes))?

```
en --> english
it --> italian
```

And what about the other way around?

```
spanish --> es
finnish --> fi
```

Of course, a possible way to do it is to download a file containing those info from the Internet (for example the file that can be found [here](https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/language-codes/language-codes_csv/data/b65af208b52970a4683fa8fde9af8e9f/language-codes_csv.csv)) and then read it line by line, extracting the info you need. However, I was wondering whether it is possible to rely only on the OS (Ubuntu, in my case): it contains info about the locales, so I guess there exists a way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash

Comment: @wallenborn I know how to create a generic dictionary. My question is about how to easily fill these specific dictionaries

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I already implemented my own dictionary filled with those info by simply downloading a file from the Internet and then parsing it line by line. However, I am not able to find a way to do the same without relying on external sources.

Comment: @Cyrus I'm using Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4894232/3266847

Comment: `it contains info about the locales` - locale is not only about language. There is no ISO 693 -like-ish field in [locale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html). You _have to_ download the list of codes and parse them, which is exactly the way to go. Also, an environment may not support all locales, but only those it needs to have. I wonder if all languages mentioned in ISO 639 have some locale.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Perl installed, you can use the core module 'Locale::Langauge' to convert 2 letter languages to name, and in reverse

```
perl -e 'use Locale::Language; print code2language("ar");'
Arabic

perl -MLocale::Language -e 'print language2code("French");'
fr
```

See https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/Locale/Language.html